# Losing Connection With Real Time Database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue on firebase; the listener is connected to realtime database with personal hotspot and gets updates from database correctly, but when the hotspoter changes the network quality from 3G to LTE (or another, doesn't matter), the listener starts to not get updates from realtime database anymore. How can I detect this issue?

Comment: Hmmm... the SDK should usually detect that the original socket stopped working and create a new one, but it may take some time. Does it not reconnect even if you wait a few minutes?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for response, yes after approximately 10 minutes it starts to work, but it is too long for user experience. I thought that Firebase would have handled this issue.

Comment: It does, but it depends on the network allowing it to detect that the socket has become non-responsive, which is unfortunately not always great on mobile providers. You could [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_:) to see what the SDK is going during those 10 minutes, or you could try to detect the situation yourself and call `goOffline()`/`goOnline` in quick succession so that the SDK creates a new connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDK uses various mechanism to detect whether the socket it uses to communicate with the server is still active, but unfortunately these are not always reliable on all (especially) mobile providers.

You could [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_:) to see what the SDK is going during those 10 minutes, or you could detect the network switch yourself and call `goOffline()`/`goOnline` in quick succession so that the SDK creates a new connection.